# Calling data in each controller vs broadcasting it/emitting it to all controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

As I have studied, we can use $emit to emit the data to all the parent controllers and $broadcast to broadcast the data to all the child controllers, while we can use $on to catch the data emitted/broadcasted from $emit/$broadcast. For getting data from an external json, we use $http.get.

If we have multiple controllers nested inside each other, is it recommended to use $http.get multiple times in each controller or use $http once in the parent controller and the data is broadcasted to all the child controllers present? Or, is it better if we have a seperate service to handle all the $http.get requests that can be further used in each of the controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function in the service and use it when you want like parent and child.

```
**Service::**

function getData() {
// Get data from API and return.
}

**Controller 1**

function getRecord() {
 // call service1.getData();
}

**Controller 2**

function getRecord() {
//  calll service1.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of which option you choose, you should call APIs (`$http` functions) from services. That makes them reusable.

Having said that, in your case broadcasting is not good idea. I would go with option #2.
Also if your response is going to be same for all the request from child controllers, try to save the response of first call into service and then reuse it.